# current time using ajax not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, symfony1

I am trying to achieve a dynamic current time on my webpage, showing hour, minutes and seconds. I'm using Ajax but this doesn't seem to be working.

Also, I'm using the Symfony framework.

In the body, I got

```
<body onload="showCurrentTime()">
```

Before that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/curr_time.js"></script>
```

curr_time.js

```
//Once the document is loaded, execute the showCurrentTIme function
//This is the AJAX function that displays the current time on the screen.
$(document).ready(function(){ showCurrentTime(); });    

function showCurrentTime() {
    //Call the current time web service,
    //grab the time off the server, and apply it to the 
    //end-user client after waiting for the document to load

    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Make the call to the XML web service
        $.get("currentDateTime.php", function(currentDateTime) {
            //Format the time returned by the server
            var time = [ $("hour", currentDateTime).text(), 
            ":", 
            $("min", currentDateTime).text() ];

            //Determine how many milliseconds to will wait until 
            //the time needs to be refreshed again
            var refresh = [(60 - $("sec", currentDateTime).text()) * 1000 ];

            //Display the time on the end-user client
            $("#currentTime").html(time.join(''));

            //Set a timer so that the time on the end-user client updates 
            // in sync with the server time to display the true current time
            setTimeout('showCurrentTime()', refresh);
        });
    });
}
```

In the same folder, I have the PHP file currentDateTime.php

```
<?php
#Need to specify that this is an XML document in order for it to work with AJAX
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

#Set variables equal to each part of the date and time
$year = date("Y"); 
$mon = date("m");
$mday = date("d");
$hour = date("H");
$min = date("i");
$sec = date("s");

#Create the XML document of the current date and time
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
echo '<currentDateTime>' . "\n";
echo "\t" . '<year>' . $year . '</year>' . "\n";
echo "\t" . '<month>' . $mon . '</month>' . "\n";
echo "\t" . '<day>' . $mday . '</day>' . "\n";
echo "\t" . '<hour>' . $hour . '</hour>' . "\n";
echo "\t" . '<min>' . $min . '</min>' . "\n";
echo "\t" . '<sec>' . $sec . '</sec>' . "\n";
echo '</currentDateTime>' . "\n";
?>
```

And in the body,

```
<p id="currentTime">--:--</p>
```

I've been trying to find the error for a long time now, but with no success...

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Have you used Firebug or something like that to examine the contents of the request that the Ajax call is posting, and the response it's getting back?  Have you verified that going to your PHP page directly is returning the expected content?

Comment: Why do you need to call to the server multiple times to get the time? I would think that you can either show the time or just use [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The other reason I ask this is that you're going to be driving lots of requests to your server to get the time, for little gain (since it can be replicated on the client end). FYI, it also seems to be working in Chrome and FF on Mac (do you also include jQuery before your curr_time.js?)

Comment: 1)It works 2) Like Rob said I don't see why you would need php for that when you can use js client side 3)You actually getting server time, which is not at all necessarily the same as visitor's.

Comment: Just curious -- why aren't you just passing a timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showCurrentTime()` function as posted does only one thing: set a `$(document).ready()` handler. You want to call it *from* document ready (which you are already doing), not set another handler inside your function. Just get rid of the extra `$(document).ready()` stuff from inside that function as follows:

```
function showCurrentTime() {

   $(document).ready(function() {  // DELETE THIS LINE

       //Make the call to the XML web service
       $.get("currentDateTime.php", function(currentDateTime) {
           // rest of your function goes here...
       });

   });  // DELETE THIS LINE
}
```

I'm sure that's the main problem.

The second problem is that when you create your `refresh` variable you're assigning it to point to an array with one element rather than to a number. Remove the square brackets.

Also, having this line in your JS file:

`$(document).ready(function(){ showCurrentTime(); });`

*and* a body onload in your HTML:

`<body onload="showCurrentTime()">`

is redundant. Pick one (preferably the one in the JS file).